# Cómo traducir correctamente una línea de código de C# a VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

Que vaya por adelantado que ya tengo una edad y que mi lenguaje de programación mayoritario sigue siendo VB.NET.

Esoy creando una WEB API 2.0 y al implementar la autenticación por Tojen con JWT me encuentro con multitud de ejemplos en C#.

Casi siempre he podido traducir sin problemas el código de C# a VB, pero me he encontrado una línea de código que no he podido traducir. Hasta lo he intentado con varios traductores online competentes, pero no hay manera.

La instrucción original en C# es la siguiente:

```
return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                        new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode) { });
```

Como he comentado antes, lo he intentado con varias plataformas de traducción online.
El resultado es el siguiente:

- Telerik

  Genera un error bastante largo y ni lo intenta
- dotnetspider.com

  Traduce más o menos pero VStudio dice que hay un error. Esta es la traducción resultante:

```
Return Threading.Tasks.Task(Of HttpResponseMessage).Factory.StartNew( >= Function() HttpResponseMessage(statusCode) As Shadows End Function)
```

- codeconverter.icsharpcode.net

  Retorna un error muy largo y lo traduce a medias
- carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator

  Traduce más o menos pero VStudio dice que hay un error. Esta es la traducción resultante:

```
Return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {  }, New HttpResponseMessage(statusCode))
```

¿Alguien podría decirme cual es su equivalente correcto en VB?

Un enorme agradecimiento por adelantado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

La conversión del código que indicas a VB.NET es la siguiente:

```
Return Task(Of HttpResponseMessage).Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                                           Return New HttpResponseMessage(statusCode)
                                                     End Function)
```

Para poder llegar a esta conclusión con cualquier tipo de código lo mejor es fraccionar el código y estudiar que es lo que hace, y entonces interpretarlo en VB.NET.